# Check if SOME array values are equal

Tags: arrays, equals

I'm looking for a way to check if some values of an array are equal, here is an example :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] //False
[1, 1, 2, 3] //True
['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', ] // True
```

I already found this method, that returns 'true' if EVERY array values are equal but it's not what I want :

```
console.log([1,1,1,1].every( (val, i, arr) => val === arr[0] ))
```

Thanks

Comment: Find array with unique values and compare lengths.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If the collection obtained by keeping only the distinct elements is smaller than the original collection, then there were duplicate elements:

```scala
val seq = Seq(1, 1, 2, 3)

seq.distinct.size < seq.size
//=> true
```

This typically runs in O(n) time and O(n) space. However, you should be able to also make it short-circuiting so that it aborts as soon as it finds a duplicate element:

```ruby
require 'set'

ary = [1, 2, 3, 1]

!ary.each_with_object(Set[]) {|el, set| break if set.include?(el); set << el }
#=> true
```